# reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that int[] conforms to T[]

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am sorting my int array in a descending order and I am getting this error. What is it about?

Error
"reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that int[] conforms to T[]"

Arrays.sort(myArray, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`. Because `Collections.reverseOrder()` expects a generic type which cannot be a primitive `int`.